# Slickest REPL console in any language

Tags: python, matlab, console

Many languages of REPL consoles with additional features like autocomplete and intellisense.  For instance, iPython, Mathematica, and PyCrust all make some effort to go beyond a basic read eval loop.  REPLs are particularly useful in languages where interactive exploration is very important, such as Matlab or R.

I'm looking for inspiration.  What application provides the slickest REPL?  Or what features do you always wish existed in your REPL of choice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really like Safari's Web Inspector Javascript console.  Specifically:

- Collapsible interactive object hierarchies
- `sprintf`-style logging
- Pretty-printing of closures, allowing you to peer into the internals of anonymous functions
- Auto-complete / hinting of object properties on the command-line

Comment: Sounds like this would complement Firebug in my web app development! Thanks

Comment: Using the latest WebKit nightly, how to I open Web Inspector?

Comment: Enable the Develop menu by going to Safari > Preferences > Advanced, and click on the "Show Develop menu in menu bar."

Answer (score 5):

Common Lisp and emacs with SLIME. All you could really want, think of, dream of, and then some.

Answer (score 3):

The command window in MATLAB 7.8.0 (R2009a) has a few nice features:

- **Tabbed-completion:** You can type part of a variable or function name, then hit tab to get a selectable list of all possible variable or function completions. This also works when typing part of a string, which will bring up a selectable list of file names in the current directory that complete the string.
- **Argument-list format display:** If you type a function name and an open parenthesis, you will automatically get a list of possible formats for the argument list along with a link to the help documentation for that function.

Here's a screenshot of the two options:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think [PowerShell](http://www.softpedia.com/screenshots/Windows-PowerShell_2.png) wins without any doubt.